# Disable select function Jquery 1.9

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following script works in all versions of Jquery except 1.9 (ahhh). It's very simple I have 5 dropdown list with the same 20 options in each list. Everytime they choose one option it is disabled and can not be chosen in the next list. And before anyone mentions the idea of using a checkbox function I did this already, and it worked great, but the big man upstair decided they want me to rewrite this script preferable.

```
    $("select").change(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var prevVal = $this.data("prev");
    var otherSelects = $("select").not(this);
    otherSelects.find("option[value=" + $(this).val('') + "]").prop('disabled', true);
    if (prevVal) {
        otherSelects.find("option[value=" + prevVal + "]").prop('disabled', false);
    }

    $this.data("prev", $this.val());
});
 function clearForm(form) {
 // iterate over all of the inputs for the form
 // element that was passed in
 $(':input', form).each(function() {
 var type = this.type;
 var tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase(); // normalize case
 // it's ok to reset the value attr of text inputs,
 // password inputs, and textareas
 if (type == 'text' || type == 'password' || tag == 'textarea')
  this.value = "";
// checkboxes and radios need to have their checked state cleared
// but should *not* have their 'value' changed
else if (type == 'checkbox' || type == 'radio')
  this.checked = false;
// select elements need to have their 'selectedIndex' property set to -1
// (this works for both single and multiple select elements)
else if (tag == 'select')
  this.selectedIndex = -1;
 });
 };
```

Comment: What errors do you get? Have you used the jQuery Migrate plugin to check for changes in versions?

Comment: You failed to mention how exactly this code doesn't work, though there's an obvious bug in the 4th line of the "change" handler.

Comment: `"option[value=" + $(this).val('') + "]"` makes no sense

Comment: Make a jsbin or jsfiddle with some more code/fake data for us to get an idea of what you are doing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abigaild12/ABHWa/40/ this is the script working like charm. @Elijan Your right attr and prop are both valid in 1.7 but I tried both prop and attr in 1.9 and neither worked. So now I am really confused and still have no idea why this script wont work in 1.9 this is the non working example http://jsfiddle.net/abigaild12/ABHWa/49/

Comment: @SLaks I think you hit the nail on the head about "option[value=" + $(this).val('') + "], any suggestions..

Comment: @abigaildiaz: That code doesn't make any sense.  You need to figure out what you're trying to do and replace it with code that does make sense.

Comment: You may want the `option:selected` selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I add the answer to this question if anyone ever needs to use this type of script:

```
$("select").change(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var prevVal = $this.data("prev");
    var otherSelects = $("select").not(this);
 var thisVal = $(this).val(); 

otherSelects.find("option:contains(" + thisVal + ")").attr('disabled', true);

    if (prevVal) {

        otherSelects.find("option:contains(" + prevVal + ")").attr('disabled', false);
    }

    $this.data("prev", $this.val());
});
```

If you want to see it in action it's here: http://jsfiddle.net/abigaild12/UQA3X/1/

Answer (score 0):

http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop-

> However, **when a selector like "input[value=abc]" is used**, it should
>   always select by the value attribute and not any change made to the
>   property by the user, for example from them typing into a text input.
>   **As of jQuery 1.9, this behaves correctly and consistently. Earlier
>   versions of jQuery would sometimes use the property when they should
>   have used the attribute.**
>   Blockquote

In other words"

```
otherSelects.find("option[value=" + $(this).val('') + "]").attr('disabled', 'disabled')

otherSelects.find("option[value=" + prevVal + "]").removeAttr('disabled');
```